# Why won't KML track/layers appear in Google maps when opened from link or embedded?

Tags: google-maps, caching, kml, kmz, mymaps

I have created several maps containing trails for a mountain in Google myMaps. 
The map has been shared and embedded in a HTML on my webpage.

What I want: Is to create a button on my webpage that opens the map in Google maps, or, embed the map in a HTML on my page, so when someone click the square icon in the top right corner, they open the map in Google maps.

The problem: When i make a button containing the link, and click the button, the kml file wont show in Google maps. Google maps will not load the file, instead it just opens google maps and show my current position. 
If i open via the embedded by clicking the square icon in the top right corner, it will show the map, but only the first time. After that, it loads the map, but without the kml track/layers that i have created.

Link: https://www.google.com/maps/d/drive?state=%7B%22ids%22%3A%5B%221wMVy8nre4OzCybhg6Mh_o_f8rRKxDvtb%22%5D%2C%22action%22%3A%22open%22%2C%22userId%22%3A%22112555612151854108744%22%7D&usp=sharing

Embed:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1wMVy8nre4OzCybhg6Mh_o_f8rRKxDvtb" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

What is the best practice for solving the problem? Is there any way i can make sure the map always opens up in Google Maps and ensure that servers do not open a cached version?

Comment: Have you made sure that your MyMaps are shared publicly?

Comment: Yes, the maps are shared. Anyone can open them in Google maps, but this only work the first time. I suspect it is because of google servers is caching, so the second and third time they open the map, they open a cached copy of the map, that does not include the tracks.. Im not sure..